# curve doesn't follow the point

Tags: pgfplots

I created this graph using pgfplot package. Here it is the code I used:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin=1e-06,xmax=1e-01,xlabel=packet loss,ylabel=valore atteso,
                         grid=both,
                         legend pos = north west]
    \addplot [smooth,thick,blue]
        file {./MATLAB/grafici/valore_atteso/pure_network_coding/var_pkts_loss_probability/valore_atteso_20nodes_rlnc.txt};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

here it is the result I got:

[image]

but unfortunately this is not the right graph. This because the file contains those values:

```
1e-06 1.0022
1e-05 1.0095
0.0001 1.0299
0.001 1.135
0.01 2.1753
0.1 46.922
```

The curve around 1e-3 and 1e-2 goes down. Why?

Comment: you have added the smooth option.

Comment: yeah right...removing smooth it works...but why doesn't work using smooth option?it should follow simply the points

Comment: If it follows the points then it cannot smoothen. The corners must be modified to be smooth and the degrees of freedom are fixed by the provided points of the curve. A final note I would not touch the data in any log plot (no matter how ugly it can be). The smallest changes are drastic in the actual magnitudes.

Comment: ok right but it would be smoothen even if the corners go to up instead to go down...

Comment: The curve should go through all the points (try adding `mark=*` to see where your points are), but between the points, the curve changes of course, otherwise it wouldn't be smooth, as percusse said.

Comment: another question: how do I set the dimension of the mark?

Comment: `mark size=<value>`

Comment: @cmhughes Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`smooth` option enables a path morphing mechanism such that the sharp corners are eliminated via some Bézier curve construction. As the name implies the curve is morphed into a smoother one. The only relation with the original curve is the given fixed points that define the curvature of the path while passing through those points.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,0) (3.3,0.5)};
\addplot+[smooth,ultra thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,0) (3.3,0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In drawings and schematics this is no big deal and can be used safely. However as you have found out, scientific plots should be given without any modification. Especially in the logarithmic plot cases the smallest deviations mean a lot in the linear scale.